# PyQT5: Связь между spinBox и comboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox, qspinbox

Помогите с логикой, пожалуйста.
Есть 2 spinBox и 2 комбобокс
При выборе значения комбобокс нужно взять значения из спинбоксов, сложить те из них у которых выбрано то же самое значение комбобокса и вывести результат сложения в `Label`.

Получился вот такой код, но при изменении значения комбобокса происходит повторное сложение, а нужно чтобы `spinBoxы` складывались только один раз.

`WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(344, 226)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 42, 22))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.power1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.power1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 60, 47, 13))
        self.power1.setObjectName("power1")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 60, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.power2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.power2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 47, 13))
        self.power2.setObjectName("power2")
        self.comboBox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 90, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox2.setObjectName("comboBox2")
        self.comboBox2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox2.addItem("")
        self.spinBox2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 42, 22))
        self.spinBox2.setObjectName("spinBox2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



#        self.spinBox2.valueChanged.connect(self.getValue2)

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkState1)
        self.comboBox2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkState2)
        self.power_AMP1 = 0
        self.power_AMP2 = 0

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.power1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Не выбран"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.power2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.comboBox2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Не выбран"))
        self.comboBox2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))



    def checkState1(self, state):

        if state == 0:
            print("Код 0")

        elif state == 1:
            print("Усилитель 1")
            self.power_AMP1 = self.power_AMP1 + self.spinBox.value()
            print(self.power_AMP1)
            self.power1.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP1))

        elif state == 2:
            print("Усилитель 2")
            self.power_AMP2 = self.power_AMP2 + self.spinBox.value()
            print(self.power_AMP2)
            self.power2.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP2))


    def checkState2(self, state):

        if state == 0:
            print("Код 0")

        elif state == 1:
            print("Усилитель 1")
            self.power_AMP1 = self.power_AMP1 + self.spinBox2.value()
            print(self.power_AMP1)
            self.power1.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP1))
        elif state == 2:
            print("Усилитель 2")
            self.power_AMP2 = self.power_AMP2 + self.spinBox2.value()
            print(self.power_AMP2)
            self.power2.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP2))



    def getValue2(self, value):
        self.power2.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b>".format(value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

С логикой - попробуйте так. Если я что-то не так понял - скажите, я подправлю.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(344, 226)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 42, 22))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.power1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.power1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 60, 47, 13))
        self.power1.setObjectName("power1")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 60, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.power2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.power2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 90, 47, 13))
        self.power2.setObjectName("power2")
        self.comboBox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(98, 90, 81, 22))
        self.comboBox2.setObjectName("comboBox2")
        self.comboBox2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox2.addItem("")
        self.spinBox2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 42, 22))
        self.spinBox2.setObjectName("spinBox2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.power1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Не выбран"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.power2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.comboBox2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Не выбран"))
        self.comboBox2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # !!!  тут ваша логика
        
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.get_value_spinBox('AMP1'))   # +++
        self.spinBox2.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.get_value_spinBox('AMP2'))  # +++
        
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkState1)
        self.comboBox2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkState2)
        self.power_AMP1 = 0
        self.power_AMP2 = 0
        self.power_AMP = 0
        
    def get_value_spinBox(self, amp):                                               # +++
        if amp == 'AMP1':
            self.power_AMP1 = self.spinBox.value()
        elif amp == 'AMP2':
            self.power_AMP2 = self.spinBox2.value()      
        self.power_AMP = self.power_AMP1 +  self.power_AMP2                         # +++  self.power_AMP 
        print(f'power_AMP1 = {self.power_AMP1}; power_AMP2 = {self.power_AMP2}; power_AMP = {self.power_AMP}')  

    def checkState1(self, state):
        print()
        if state == 0:
            print("Код 0")
            self.power1.setText("TextLabel")
            if not self.comboBox2.currentIndex():
                self.power2.setText("TextLabel")
        elif state == 1:
            print(f"Усилитель 1 {self.power_AMP}")
            self.power1.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP))  # power_AMP
        elif state == 2:
            print(f"Усилитель 2 {self.power_AMP}")
            self.power2.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP))  # power_AMP

    def checkState2(self, state):
        print()
        if state == 0:
            print("Код 0")
            self.power2.setText("TextLabel")
            if not self.comboBox.currentIndex():
                self.power1.setText("TextLabel")
        elif state == 1:
            print(f"Усилитель 1 {self.power_AMP}")
            self.power1.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP))
        elif state == 2:
            print(f"Усилитель 2 {self.power_AMP}")
            self.power2.setText("<b style='color: blue;'> {} </b> Вт".format(self.power_AMP))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    '''
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    '''
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]